# Find number of positive integers less than 101 that can't be expressed as difference of squares of two integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find number of positive integers less than 101 that cant be 
expressed as difference of squares of two integers.
my attempt:
$a^2-b^2= N$
now should i go on solving for each N less than 101?

Comment: You just have to look at integers of form 4k+2. This is a well studied problem.. a quick google may help

Answer (score 3):

Notice that every odd number can be expressed as the difference of two squares: namely, $2n+1=(n+1)^2-n^2$. Moreover, if $m=4n$, then $m=(2n+1)+(2n-1)$, so $m=(n+1)^2-(n-1)^2$.

On the other hand, if $m$ is $2$ times an odd number, it cannot be expressed as a difference of squares: arguing mod $4$, $a^2-b^2$ can only be equal to $0$, $1$ or $-1$, whereas $m\equiv 2$ mod $4$.

Hence the answer to your question is $25$.

Comment: however, if $m$ is $2$ times an odd number, it can be expressed as the sum of $2$ differences of squares. It's enough to decompose the even number into a sum of $2$ odd numbers and decompose both odd numbers into a difference of squares. Example by writing $10=3+7$, we can then write $3=2^2-1^2$ and $7=4^2-3^2$. Then $10=(2^2-1^2) + (4^2-3^2)$.